# How to set overlay image on ListviewItem in virtual mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listview with virtual `mode = true`, and `View = View.Details;`.
I need to overlay an image to the already present icon of the ListViewItem present in it.

Does anybody have any idea about it?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: There's no built-in capability.  You'll need to set OwnerDraw = True so you can write your own DrawItem event handler.  Be sure to check the MSDN docs for ListView.OwnerDraw

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reason why our company developed and started using [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview).
There is also a freeware edition Better ListView Express.

It does not support virtual mode, but it is fast enough with excellent owner drawing support. You can keep the look and feel of the default ListView and add whatever you like on top of it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Libor for the info.
but i need to implement it in Virtual mode.